# change permalinks to 'Postname' cause Page Not Found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, wordpress

I have a `query` to `fetch` all post from a custom post type `device` and I want to display 3 post per page. using the `next` and `previous` link, I able to navigate the next page where another 3 post can see. it work perfectly with the default `permalink` which is

```
  //the default permalink of wordpress
http:mywebsite/?p=123
```

and I need to change it into `Post name` for SEO purposes which is like this:

```
http:mywebsite/sample-post/
```

and then suddenly the problem appear.

I've searching and reading more blog/article but I can't find any helpful suggestion. I'm so stuck with this problem it give me a headache.

by the way I used this query:

```
   <?php
     if (have_posts()) : {
     $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
     query_posts('showposts=3&post_type=advice'.'&paged='.$paged);} ?>

      <ul class="adviceLandingPage">

      <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

       <li>
         <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
         <span><?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,20); ?></span>

       </li>

       <?php endwhile; ?>
          <li class="navigation">
             <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
          </li>
       </u>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

thank you for any suggestion.

**Edit:**

*when I navigate to the next page, where I assume to see the next 3 post, this is the error `Page not found`.*

and this is the .htaccess after changing the permalink to %postname%

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bryan/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /bryan/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Can you give more information, for example what is the error that is occurring, or can you post a link to the site so we can see the problem?

Comment: when I navigate the next page this is the error is this `page not found`

Comment: We don't really have enough here to go on. The problem doesn't seem to be with the loop so the code included doesn't help. Some ideas to help troubleshoot the problem - are the correct urls being generated in the navigation? Are you using a custom theme?

Comment: the problem only appear if i change the permalink into `Post name` but i use the default permalink there is no problem navigating to the next page.

Comment: Its very difficult to try to work out the problem, there are so many factors in a WP site. This link might be helpful http://theme-fusion.com/knowledgebase/custom-permalinks-return-404-errors/

Comment: I'd **avoid** using `query_posts()` if you can!

Answer (score 9):

To fix this problem, do the following steps:

1. find the `httpd.conf` file on the Web server
2. Find the code `LoadModule rewrite_module modules / mod_rewrite.so`
3. removing the `#` in front of it
4. find the code `AllowOverride none` and convert to `AllowOverride all`

It's as simple as delicious :)

Comment: Yeah ok this is the idea but with apache2 the procedure would be:   
 create the simlink``/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load -> ../mods-available/rewrite.load`` then edit ``/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`` and change ``AllowOverride none`` to ``AllowOverride all``.

Answer (score 7):

**Run the following commands**

**NB: The `$` Is not part of the commands**

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite

$ cd /var/www/html

$ ls -al

$ sudo touch .htaccess

$ sudo nano .htaccess
```

**Modify your `.htaccess` file to look the snippet above**

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

---

```
$ sudo chmod 644 .htaccess

$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

**Make sure the `AllowOverride All` is set**

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

---

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

See the link below for more on this.

https://sachinparmarblog.com/fixing-permalinks-on-wordpress-to-use-postname/

Answer (score 1):

Also check the `httpd.conf` file and make sure `AllowOverride` is `All` for the directory that holds the `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you already fixed this, but usually all you need to do is flush the db, login to your site a go to permalinks and just make a change and save it and if that doesn't help

read this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix.

Go into the WordPress admin dashboard, go to:

“Settings” > “Permalinks” > “Common settings”, and set the radio button to “Custom Structure”

, and paste into the text box:

/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

, and click the Save button.

Comment: This worked for me but I don't understand why it works or what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

this happens to me when I didn't give write access to the .htaccess file. changing permission of .htaccess file  solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem in `Settings-> Permalinks` check `Post name` and copying the content of `.htacces`, which is shown when you save. Access the web hosting and modify the `.htaccess` and paste the content and save

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact scenario after updating to https/SSL using a LetsEncrypt cert.

The instructions in the URL below are valid, however instead of updating 000-default.conf, I had to update the ssl conf file with the "AllowOverride All".

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/domainname-le-ssl.conf
```

https://sachinparmarblog.com/fixing-permalinks-on-wordpress-to-use-postname/

Comment: This was similar to my issue with the Let's Encrypt cert. In the directory override, it had the path as /var/www/wordpress when obviously it had to be switched to /var/www/mydomainname/ in order to work properly.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using nginx and want to change wordpress permlinks from plain to Post name simply add following line into nginx file

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

and if your wordpress is install in specific folder example /blog then add this

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```